# Is there a specific word for financial records?

Tags: word-difference, translation, terminology

I'm writing a banking software that, using some accounts from a bank, show the records about it. They could be debt records (money leaving account) or credit records (money arriving). Is there a specific word for the unit inside this group of records that together build the account history? I'm a Brazilian and using Google Translate, I searched for "lançamento". But this ambiguous portuguese word also means launch (like a rocket launch), which I think is not the case. I also found release, but I also think that's not the case (like a software being released into the consumer market). The word "lançamento" means to input/throw/launch(?) some data into an account.

Comment: Are you looking for transaction?

Comment: **the unit inside this group of records** is unclear.  I don't know what you mean by "inside".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I meant a single record. What I tried to say is like "a unit inside a molecule is an atom" or "A unit defined at a cattle in a pasture is a single ox"

Comment: @Mahdi, I think transaction fits my description, but since in portuguese we have "transação" which is the same I was thinking if there's a specific non translatable word for transaction/record specifically used on financial market

Comment: financial records are made up of accounts and accounting statements. You are not writing **a**software: you are writing software, a software program or a software application. Banking records can be credit and debit accounts. Or bank statements. We say: to record data [in an account]. Record or enter or input data. And lançar is not right here in Portuguese either.

Comment: To use your molecule example, the molecule is the "transaction" and the atoms within it would be edits to two account records, one showing a debit and the other a credit.  A transaction is a "logical" unit consisting of two related memorialized "actual" items.

Comment: There is even the term of art **atomic transaction** although there "atomic" is your "molecular" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google translate provides a number of additional suggestions aside from "launch", including the one I think you're looking for: "entry".  A *financial record* (or *journal*) is a record of individual *entries* for a particular *account*.  These entries are (usually) either *debits* and *credits* to that account. Example:

> Double-entry bookkeeping, in accounting, is a system of bookkeeping so named because every **entry** to an account requires a corresponding and opposite **entry** to a different account.

[More information on double-entry bookkeeping](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/sac-finaccounting/chapter/the-double-entry-accounting-method/)

Other examples:

> A **journal entry** is a formal accounting entry used to identify a business transaction. The **entry** itemizes accounts that are debited and credited, and should include some description of the reason for the **entry**, as well as the date.
>
> If properly documented, **journal entries** provide an excellent audit trail for anyone investigating the accounting records of an entity.
>
> *Adjusting **Journal Entry***: An accounting **entry** made into a subsidiary ledger called the General journal to account for a periods changes, omissions or other financial data required to be reported "in the books" but not usually posted to the journals used for typical period transactions.

Comment: Good for you, making heads or tails out of it. I simply had no idea what was actually meant. As for launch, it is irrelevant.

Comment: @Lambie it's just one of those quirks of language, where a word used for, say, *launching a product* (lançamento de produto) is also used for bookkeeping entry (lançamento contábil).  But English is no different -- why is it when we *discharge* someone from employment we *fire* them?  Seems a cruel metaphor.

Comment: I speak fluent Portuguese. Did you know that? That said, what is described by the OP is not really connected to launching a product. In fact, the question is simply not clear.

Comment: @Lambie  I did not know, but I'll remember that for the future.  I've just been watching a Portuguese TV show so all I know is a few *colorful* phrases.  :)

Answer (score 2):

As Tᴚoɯɐuo says in a comment, I think *transaction* is a good word to use here. It's common and readily understandable, but not overly informal.

Most monthly bank statements include a "transaction history" which shows the debits and credits to an account.

Comment: I believe this is the best overall word.